# Android XML ImageView

Tags: android, xml

I've been trying to find an answer to this all of last evening with no luck so I decided to come ask here. I just started getting into front end dev for Android apps and I'm trying to do something really simple that just doesn't work. All I want to do is add an image on the screen and be able to resize it EXACTLY what size I want regardless of proportions. This is the code I'm currently using inside a relative layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/statsus_logo" />
```

My image is a horizontal rectangle. When I first add it, it shows up inside a small square centered with a bit of padding all around. When I make the width 400dp that square appears to strech almost 100% across the screen however the logo stays the EXACT same size, centered vertically and horizontally inside this imageview container. When I increase the height of the imageview, the logo increases its size but almost as if it was taking the height and using it as a width. I feel like what its trying to do right now is use the height as its width and the only time when its width is the value i put in, is if the height is also the same value and even then there's some extra unwanted padding.

Again, all I want is for this damn image to be the size I tell it to, so if I want it 5dp wide and 100dp tall, it does just that. Can anyone please help? Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: yes and that seems to strech my image properly but now there's still a bunch of padding around my logo especially above and bellow it.. if I set the height to 400 for example, there's probably at least another 400 above and bellow it instead of making my image 400dp.. so it works for width but not height

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute to your imageview

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

[Scale type reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: Actually I think that's heading the right way. Now my image did stretch, but there's still quite a bit of padding inside the imageview box. Anyway I can remove that so it only covers the image?

Comment: can you add image? current state and what do you want to achive

Comment: Come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people) and get a chat

Comment: my reputation isn't high enough :(

Comment: android:layout_height="200dp" - its the code above.. the second image is edited in photoshop

Comment: i can't reply in that chatroom because my stackoverflow reputation isn't high enough

Comment: Just decrease the height or let it wrap_content so it the same as the input image?

Comment: decreasing the height just scales everything so it looks the same but within 100dp instead of 200dp.. so there's still all that padding there, the logo is just now thinner.. and if I do wrap_content then I can't set the height to what I want : /

Answer (score 0):

android:scaleType="fitXY" is the way to scale your image however you want without keeping your proportions however my issue was a little bit different... I'm using android studio and for some reason the settings I was using to "add a new image asset" was making my image act the way I described it above... if I just add an image manually by just click and dragging into the folder, then the image works the way I want it... so long story short, the issue was with how I added my new image asset

thanks to everyone for all of your answers and help!